# Something went wrong with you. Something went wrong to you

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, sentence-meaning

Something went wrong with you. 
Something went wrong to you. 
Which is the correct answer? 
What is the difference between them?

Comment: Something is *wrong **with** X* is the idiomatic way of saying that something about *X* is amiss or troubling or screwy.  *Wrong **to** X* is not an expression with a fixed meaning, though of course it may occur by chance in contexts which call for an ordinary preposition phrase headed by *to*: "He said something wrong **to you**".

Comment: Sir,  Can't I say? Something went wrong to you.

Comment: Not if what you mean is that "Something about you was not working as it should" or "Something was troubling you". If what you mean is that "Something was sent to you by mistake" you **might** say "Something went to you wrongly", but that's not a very likely way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *to* you

is indicating movement, direction or intention toward you.

> I am sending the package **to you**.
>   I am speaking **to you**.
>   Happy Birthday **to you**!

Similar to your example, you could say:

> Something happened **to you**.

which indicates an action (ex. What happened was that I hit my finger with a hammer).

As for your example:

> Something is/went wrong **with you**.

is better, because it is more about describing your current state or condition, not movement (generally the case using *to be*).